# How to loop through a list of urls for web scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Does anyone know how to scrape a list of urls from the same website by Beautifulsoup? list = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'...]

==========================================================================

My code to extract a list of urls:

```
url = 'http://www.hkjc.com/chinese/racing/selecthorsebychar.asp?ordertype=2'
url1 = 'http://www.hkjc.com/chinese/racing/selecthorsebychar.asp?ordertype=3'
url2 = 'http://www.hkjc.com/chinese/racing/selecthorsebychar.asp?ordertype=4'

r  = requests.get(url)
r1  = requests.get(url1)
r2  = requests.get(url2)

data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
links = []

for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'title_text'}):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

data1 = r1.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data1, 'lxml')

for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'title_text'}):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

data2 = r2.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data2, 'lxml')

for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'title_text'}):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

new = ['http://www.hkjc.com/chinese/racing/']*1123

url_list = ['{}{}'.format(x,y) for x,y in zip(new,links)]
```

code to extract from a single page of url:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import requests  
import pandas as pd  

url = 'myurl'

r = requests.get(myurl)

r.encoding = 'utf-8'

html_content = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')

soup.findAll('tr')[27].findAll('td')

column_headers = [th.getText() for th in
                  soup.findAll('tr')[27].findAll('td')]

data_rows =soup.findAll('tr')[29:67]
data_rows

player_data = [[td.getText() for td in data_rows[i].findAll('td', {'class':['htable_text', 'htable_eng_text']})]
            for i in range(len(data_rows))]

player_data_02 = []

for i in range(len(data_rows)):
    player_row = []

    for td in data_rows[i].findAll('td'):
        player_row.append(td.getText())

    player_data_02.append(player_row)

df = pd.DataFrame(player_data, columns=column_headers[:18])
```

Comment: your question is not completely understandable. Please rephrase it and post realurl from where you want to scrape urls

Comment: In short, I'm looking for ways to scrape html tables from a list of urls(from the same website).

Comment: again, I can't help you while I don't see the site itself. Abstraction is good in general, but not in this case.
Please give full fist of URLs or at least a subset if you're sure that markup is the same

Comment: oops...sorry, just forget to attach the url: ['http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=S217', 'http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=A129'...]

Comment: How is this even a question? Put your scraping code in a function, then call that in a loop...

Comment: Sorry man, I'm new to python. I don't have any idea to put that in a loop. Appreciate if you could show me the whole picture.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on your links subset collection of table data goes like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests  
import pandas as pd  

url_list = ['http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=S217','http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=A093','http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=V344','http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=V077', 'http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=P361', 'http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=T103']


for link in url_list:
    r = requests.get(link)
    r.encoding = 'utf-8'

    html_content = r.text
    soup = BS(html_content, 'lxml')


    table = soup.find('table', class_='bigborder')
    if not table:
        continue

    trs = table.find_all('tr')

    if not trs:
        continue #if trs are not found, then starting next iteration with other link

    headers = trs[0]
    headers_list=[]
    for td in headers.find_all('td'):
        headers_list.append(td.text)
    headers_list+=['Season']
    headers_list.insert(19,'pseudocol1')
    headers_list.insert(20,'pseudocol2')
    headers_list.insert(21,'pseudocol3')

    res=[]
    row = []
    season = ''
    for tr in trs[1:]:
        if 'Season' in tr.text:
            season = tr.text

        else:
            tds = tr.find_all('td')
            for td in tds:
                row.append(td.text.strip('\n').strip('\r').strip('\t').strip('"').strip()) #clean data
            row.append(season.strip())
            res.append(row)
            row=[]

    res = [i for i in res if i[0]!='']

    df=pd.DataFrame(res, columns=headers_list)
    del df['pseudocol1'],df['pseudocol2'],df['pseudocol3']
    del df['VideoReplay']

    df.to_csv('/home/username/'+str(url_list.index(link))+'.csv')
```

if you want to store data from all tables to one dataframe, this little modification will do the trick:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests  
import pandas as pd  

url_list = ['http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=S217','http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=A093','http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=V344','http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=V077', 'http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=P361', 'http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=T103']


res=[] #placing res outside of loop
for link in url_list:
    r = requests.get(link)
    r.encoding = 'utf-8'

    html_content = r.text
    soup = BS(html_content, 'lxml')


    table = soup.find('table', class_='bigborder')
    if not table:
        continue

    trs = table.find_all('tr')

    if not trs:
        continue #if trs are not found, then starting next iteration with other link


    headers = trs[0]
    headers_list=[]
    for td in headers.find_all('td'):
        headers_list.append(td.text)
    headers_list+=['Season']
    headers_list.insert(19,'pseudocol1')
    headers_list.insert(20,'pseudocol2')
    headers_list.insert(21,'pseudocol3')

    row = []
    season = ''
    for tr in trs[1:]:
        if 'Season' in tr.text:
            season = tr.text

        else:
            tds = tr.find_all('td')
            for td in tds:
                row.append(td.text.strip('\n').strip('\r').strip('\t').strip('"').strip())
            row.append(season.strip())
            res.append(row)
            row=[]

res = [i for i in res if i[0]!=''] #outside of loop

df=pd.DataFrame(res, columns=headers_list) #outside of loop
del df['pseudocol1'],df['pseudocol2'],df['pseudocol3'] 
del df['VideoReplay']

df.to_csv('/home/Username/'+'tables.csv') #outside of loop
```

Comment: man I've spent a bunch of time on this, it should _really_ be worth it

Comment: @JAY.Y, any feedback? 
did my solution help?

Comment: Appreciate that. But it returns as: name 'season' is not defined.

Comment: fixed, added season variable assignment, try again please

Comment: season is a variable that collects text from Season rows

Comment: There's another problem, the resulted dataframe only consists the table scraped from the 2nd url

Comment: I found a little bug in my code, why it's processing always the 2nd link.
fixed it, now it should save 2 different csv files

Comment: Error again-> trs = table.find_all('tr')    
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: on my PC everything is working. this error tells you that there are no such 
`tr` elements on a _particular_ page. 
You are launching this script only on pages that you initially posted or added some other pages?

Comment: added a fix that will pass a link if there are no `tr`s. I put it there without testing it, because you didn't provide urls where table is present, but `tr`s in it are not. But I think it should work now.

Comment: Ah...actually I wanna scrape all the race records of all horses from here: http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/SelectHorse.asp  I see there are some horses without any records, for example this:http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=A354   and I believe that's the point. Is it possible to get rid of that?

Comment: Added that my scraped url list dose involve those horses without any records.

Comment: added error check for table existing, now should work at last=)

Comment: So did it help in the end of the day?

Comment: I've tried that and it returns: KeyError: 'VideoReplay'

Comment: I tried to get rid of that by removing the del df['VideoReplay'], though it did not return any errors but nothing came out. Really frustrated by that.

Comment: what do you mean "nothing came out"?

Comment: nothing was shown when I tried to print the output.

Comment: you launched my code on links that are defined at the beginning of script?

Comment: I launched your 2nd script(all tables in one dataframe), of coz I did make adjustment to the statement of: url list = .....

Comment: I know the problem, I gave you the eng ver. url but I'm using chi  ver. in my code. Fortunately it works well when I switch the above urls to chi ver. However when I replaced the three urls to a list of long one, nothing came out as well.

Comment: modify your initial question - add there full URL list

Comment: I've just attached that  as well.

Comment: man what the hell? of course nothing will be listed as output in your links, there are no tables of _Horse Form Records_. Only _List By Trainer_ tables

Comment: if you want to iterate every trainer on those pages, that's _another_ task, and it's not small.

Comment: I don't understand, the extracted list is like this:  ['http://www.hkjc.com/chinese/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=S217',   'http://www.hkjc.com/chinese/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=A093',   'http://www.hkjc.com/chinese/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=V344',  'http://www.hkjc.com/chinese/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=V077',  'http://www.hkjc.com/chinese/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=P361',  'http://www.hkjc.com/chinese/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=T103',...]  What's the difference?

Comment: I inserted links from your last comment in both versions of my code, but replaced chinese version on english. Should work. Check and tell me.

Comment: but the problem is there are more than these links actually. I just listed some in my last comment.

Comment: My original plan is scraping all the urls of all horses into a list and then iterate through the list to scrape all the race records of every horses.

Comment: genious plan.
But that's another big subtask and I won't do it because I'm tired already.
I spent too much time on your problem by not fixing or degugging _your_ code, but WRITING FROM SCRATCH _my_ code. 
My code solves 50% of your end purpose. Further go without me. To accept my solution or not, that's on your conscience.

Comment: Of coz I would accept your solution. You do help me a lot and I'm really appreciate that.

Comment: ok, I've chilled-out a little, there were too much emotions in my 2 last comments, I' should be more calm. I read that you're new in python, I understand everything, couple of years ago python was new to me too. If you want I can advice you some free courses to get you familiar with python. After that scraping might go easier. At least you'll understand looping and other useful stuff=).

Comment: It's ok dude, I know it's frustrated and I really appreciate for what you've done. Actually I'm taking some free python courses at the same time when I'm working on this problem. And of course that would be wonderful if you could give me some material or direction to let me finish the rest by my own.

Comment: you really went above and beyond, bravo buddy.