# Possibility to get content of urls with headers and write it to a file (python 3.7)

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I have multiple urls that differ in query strings parameters, maily in days, for instance:

`urls = [f'https://example.com?query=from-{x+1}d+TO+-{x}d%data' for x in range(10)]`

I want to write the content of all these urls to just one file. I tried with urllib.requests:

```
import urllib.request

key = "some value"
requests = urllib.request.Request([url for url in urls], headers={"key":key})
<urllib.request.Request object at 0x7f48e8381490>
```

but the first pitfall is that 'Request' object is not iterable

```
responses = urllib.request.urlopen([request for request in requests])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Request' object is not iterable
```

Ideally the result could go to a file as below:

```
data = open('file_name', 'a')
data.write([response.read() for response in responses])
```

I also tried with requests lib

```
import requests
test = requests.Session()
r = test.get([url for url in urls], headers={"key":key})
```

but this fails with

```
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for <list of urls>
```

Is there a way to get the content of these urls with headers and to send it to a file?

Comment: Iterate over the list and pass one url at a time. And check the urls in the list, because I don't think you have them right

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through a list of urls for web scraping with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823278/how-to-loop-through-a-list-of-urls-for-web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you might want to do something like this:

```
import urllib.request

with open("file_name", "a") as data:
    for url in urls:
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={"key": "key"})
        with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
            html = response.read()
            data.write(html)
```

Comment: Thanks! I've modified it a bit

`reqs = [urllib.request.Request(url, headers={"key": key}) for url in urls]

respos = [urllib.request.urlopen(req) for req in reqs]

file.write(str([resp.read() for resp in respos]))
434640
`

and the file has  `[b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b''][b'{content.....]`

looks like the file has only the last response. Is there a way to iterate here in one line? smth similar to 
`file.write(str([urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request(url, headers={"key": "key"})).read() for url in urls]))`

Comment: Why do you want to do something like that?

Comment: Mainly to have all responses in the output file. I need this as a one-liner because the application I'm working with is not that flexible and processes mostly lambdas and one-liners. legacy code as it is