# BeautifulSoup scrape URLs located within a csv then output to new csv

Tags: python

hope you're staying safe during this corona period.

I'm pretty new to python.

I am trying to scrape a website that sells car tyres. I am trying to get the 'Brand', 'Model', 'Price' of all the tyres in each of the URLs within 'urls.csv' and then export it to another csv. Here is a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/fbd3y1me) of the URLs within my urls.csv if it is any help.

I have searched on here for similar questions including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823278/how-to-loop-through-a-list-of-urls-for-web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup). However, even then they are pasting the URLs into the code and run that. I want to have clean code that looks into my csv and fetches the first URL, scrape it, put the results into the output csv then going back to the csv and getting the second URL, scrape it, put it on the second line of the output csv.

I have managed to make a scraper that can scrape a single URL when I manually put that URL into the code.(which was a big deal for me haha). My current code:

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

#I want to be able to swap this request for every URL in the csv
page = requests.get('https://www.beaurepaires.com.au/tyresize/155W_70R_13')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

tyres = soup.find(class_='comp-product-details products-grid')

items = tyres.find_all(class_='item')

brand = [str(item.find(class_='dealer-logo')).split(' ')[1].split('=')[1].split('"')[1] for item in items]
model = [item.find(class_='product-title').get_text() for item in items]
price = [item.find(class_='main-price').get_text().split('/')[0].split(' ')[1] for item in items]

tyre_stuff = pd.DataFrame({
        'brand':brand, 
        'model':model, 
        'price':price, 
    })
print(tyre_stuff)
tyre_stuff.to_csv('beaurepaires_01.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

Can someone point me to the right direction? I think I have to import csv and also I have a feeling I will not be able to use '.to_csv' command. I also feel I might have to use urllib or something similar.

EDIT1: Here are the URLs in my csv format

```
https://www.beaurepaires.com.au/tyresize/145W_65R_15
https://www.beaurepaires.com.au/tyresize/155W_65R_13
https://www.beaurepaires.com.au/tyresize/155W_65R_14
https://www.beaurepaires.com.au/tyresize/155W_70R_13
```

EDIT2: Here is my updated code as per Paul's help but I am still stuck on how to get csv.DictWriter working to output my results

```
def get_products(url):

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    for item in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "product-item show-online-price"}):
        title = item["title"]
        brand = item.find("img", {"class": "dealer-logo"})["alt"]
        price = item.find("span", {"class": "price"}).getText()

        yield {
            "title": title,
            "brand": brand,
            "price": price
        }


def get_all_products(filename):

    import csv

    with open(filename, "r", newline="") as file:
        for tokens in csv.reader(file):
            url = tokens[0]
            for product in get_products(url):
                yield product

def main():

    from time import sleep
    from random import randint
    import csv

    sleep(randint(3,11))

    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['title', 'brand','price']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    for product in get_all_products("urls.csv"):
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'title', 'brand', 'price'})
        print(product)


    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Could you post the urls in the format of the csv? specifically the csv you use, it doesn't need to have all the urls, just an example of the format will suffice

Comment: The csv format you posted seems to be separated by a new line, that does not look like a csv usecase to me, why not just save that as text?

Comment: Loop for (url) lines in csv file

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe? Right now it just prints the products as the requests are made, but it should be pretty easy to write them to a csv file. `get_products` is a generator that yields all the products from a given URL as dictionaries. It's called `get_products` rather than `get_product` because a given URL may have more than one product.

`get_all_products` is another generator that yields every product yielded by `get_products` for every URL in a given csv filename.

As others have mentioned, there isn't really any reason for you to save your URLs in a csv file, since you don't have comma separated values, or values seperated by delimiters of any kind. You just have a bunch of URLs, so why not store them in a plain text file? It would reduce a few lines of code, even.

```
def get_products(url):

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    for item in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "product-item show-online-price"}):
        title = item["title"]
        price = item.find("span", {"class": "price"}).getText()
        logo = item.find("img", {"class": "dealer-logo"})["src"]

        yield {
            "title": title,
            "price": price,
            "logo": logo
        }

def get_all_products(filename):

    with open(filename, "r", newline="") as file:
        for url in file.readlines():
            for product in get_products(url.strip()):
                yield product

def main():

    from csv import DictWriter

    with open("products.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
        field_names = ["title", "price", "logo"]
        writer = DictWriter(file, fieldnames=field_names)

        writer.writeheader()
        for product in get_all_products("urls.txt"):
            writer.writerow(product)
            file.flush()
            print(product)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Thank you. You are correct, along with others, my 'csv' of URLs should not be a csv but rather should be a text file.

I wanted to ask two questions
(1) I wanted to implement 'sleep' as well so as to not bombard the server, where should I put the sleep command? Should it be within def main()?
(2) What way should I export the results to a new csv? Will to_csv('output.csv', mode='a', header=False) work if I insert that after print(product)?

Comment: @AftabBismi If you want to sleep between requests, you would add a `time.sleep` in the for loop in `get_all_products`. If you want to write the data to a csv file, I would look into `csv.DictWriter`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter. You would create such a `DictWriter` object before the for loop in the `main` function, and then invoke your `DictWriter` object's `writerow` method inside the loop. This would be easy to implement since every product is technically a dictionary. However, I think JSON would make more sense than csv.

Comment: Thank you very much @Paul M. I have made Edit 2 on my original question with my current code. However, I am still stuck on how to invoke DictWriter to export my scraping to csv. Please let me know what your suggestions/fixed code would look like. Cheers!

Comment: Also just to be clear, I wanted to write the entire dictionary of scraping hundreds of pages to a single csv, does this current code cover that?

Comment: @AftabBismi I've edited my code - you should be able to save all the product infos from all your pages in a single csv. Notice, I've changed the order of the key-value pairs in `get_products`, the price comes before the logo now, and that change will be reflected in the csv (I just think it looks prettier) - that means the order of the `DictWriter` fieldnames also needs to change. I've also changed the code to accept a text file containing all the URLs, rather than a csv. Also I think you probably don't need to sleep between requests - you don't need to worry about overwhelming the servers.

Comment: @AftabBismi One other thing I forgot to mention: If some of the data you are scraping for whatever reason happens to contain a comma (or whatever the delimiter of your output csv file happens to be), then you may also want to purge such characters from your scraped data before you write it to the csv file. Otherwise, it will be interpreted as a delimiter whenever you are reading from the csv file.

Answer (score 1):

First off, let's wrap up the main scraping code in a function. We can later pass just the `url` to this function (and maybe also an enumeration index) for convenience and readability.

```py
def scrape(url, index):
    page = requests.get(url, index)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    tyres = soup.find(class_='comp-product-details products-grid')

    items = tyres.find_all(class_='item')

    brand = [str(item.find(class_='dealer-logo')).split(' ')[1].split('=')[1].split('"')[1] for item in items]
    model = [item.find(class_='product-title').get_text() for item in items]
    price = [item.find(class_='main-price').get_text().split('/')[0].split(' ')[1] for item in items]

    tyre_stuff = pd.DataFrame({
        'brand':brand, 
        'model':model, 
        'price':price, 
    })
    print(tyre_stuff)
    tyre_stuff.to_csv(f'beaurepaires_{index}.csv', header=False)
```

Now let's make the loop for passing in the url, after reading the csv ofcourse.

```py
import csv

# other code

with open('links.csv', newline='') as links_file:
    links = csv.reader(links_file, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

    for i, link in enumerate(links):
        scrape(link, i)
```

Now that example, is directly from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader). The parameters might need to change according to your specific csv format, but the main idea will surely be the same.

After reading in the links, you simply have to enumerate through them (basically looping but also keeping track of the index) and pass both the link/url and the iteration number (index) to the function.

To address your concerns, I don't know why you "feel like" you need to use urllib, and also why you "feel like" `.to_csv` will not work. If your `DataFrame` resulted in the data you want, doing `.to_csv` is very much valid. However you may want to look at the parameters, demonstrated [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)